# How to receive a event on android checkbox check change?

Tags: android, events, checkbox

What would be the correct way of receiving and sending an event when a check box gets enabled or disabled?

In C# I could just easily double click and all the code would be done for me. But in android it appears to be a bit more obscure. I thought of using the touch event handlers but then if the user has a keyboard it won't detect the change since it's not touch. I figure android should have a native event for check box state change.

Comment: There's nothing "obscure" about coding by typing the code by yourself instead of click your way to it.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

```
CheckBox repeatChkBx = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer, I'm curious what would be the best approach when the checkbox is inside a ListView item and the onCheckedChange gets called every time the user scrolls past it.  Any way to differentiate when it is initiated by the user and by the listview update?

Comment: ^this comment of @Rmooney is GOLD! I had an issue with RecyclerView adapter and every time I scrolled it went crazy calling more than once! Thanks!

Comment: In the adapter, when you set the checkchange for that particular holder. First remove the listener, change the value, then readd the listener. The checkboxes themselves force call the listener so you have to remove it to set the value without it triggering.

Answer (score 8):

Since CheckBox (eventually) extends View, you can use a standard OnClickListener to detect when the CheckBox is actually tapped by the user (as opposed to the ListView updates):

```
CheckBox repeatChkBx = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
repeatChkBx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if ( ((CheckBox)v).isChecked() ) {
            // perform logic
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not be triggered if the user decided to drag the switch rather than click it.

Comment: @Silvia H      A CheckBox is not a Switch. There's nothing you could drag on a CheckBox.

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin:

```
   checkBoxView.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        print("checked: $isChecked")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

```
CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (checkbox.isChecked())
            {
             //Perform action when you touch on checkbox and it change to selected state
            }
            else
            {
   //Perform action when you touch on checkbox and it change to unselected state
            }
        }
    });
```