# Numbered Checkboxes in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-checkbox

I want the user to be able to rank a list of fruits in the order that they like to most.

Say for example, consider the list as "Mango, Apple, Banana, Pineapple".

If they like Apple, Mango, Pineapple, Banana in this order I want to use checkboxes that show the rank when the user clicks on them.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Any thing is possible if you dare to do. What have you done so far ?

Comment: I've tried using NumberPicker, but that enables the user to select same rank for the fruits.

Comment: As much as i understand you can try [this libary](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) for better user experience  , or you can use radio group too .

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with Checkboxes, take a look here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149414/how-to-receive-a-event-on-android-checkbox-check-change](http://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/3149414/how-to-receive-a-event-on-android-checkbox-check-change)

If I understood you right, you just have to set a variable when the user clicks on one of those checkboxes like:

```
  var number1 = 'Mango'
```

You should achive this with the example you can find in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with a counter. It start's at 0, when user press a checkbox you just add 1 to it and you have an array for each checkbox where you will save the number pressed.

You have `final int[] fruits = new int[4];` and `final int counter = 0;`

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
// Is the view now checked?
boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

// Check which checkbox was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.checkbox_mango:
        if (checked) {
            counter++;
            fruits[0] = counter;
        } else {
            counter--;
            fruits[0] = 0;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.checkbox_apple:
        if (checked) {
            counter++;
            fruits[1] = counter;
        } else {
            counter--;
            fruits[1] = 0;
        }
        break;
    //OTHER CASES
}
```

}