# Android: Do something when checkBox is checked

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have created custom adapter and two layouts files
the first layout is fragment view which contains  `ListView` and `Button`

the second layout contains items which will be represented in the `ListView`

**So**

I want when the `Checkbox` is check make `Button` visible

All of these operations will be done in my custom adapter class

This is myCustom Adapter

**Updated**

```
public class LampControllerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
List<LampModel> mLampModels;
HashMap<Long,LampModel> selection;
Button sC;

  public LampControllerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LampModel> lampList) {

    mContext = context;
    mLampModels = lampList;
    selection = new HashMap<Long,LampModel>();
    LayoutInflater in = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v = in.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,null);
   sC = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.selection_control);



}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mLampModels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mLampModels.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    final LampModel model = (LampModel) getItem(i);
    if (view == null) {
        // Inflating The Layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lamp_controller_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lamp_item_name);
        holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lamp_item_description);
        holder.select = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.lamp_item_select);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    holder.name.setText(model.getName());
    holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
    holder.select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if(b){
                selection.put(model.getId(),model);
            }else {
                selection.remove(model.getId());
            }

            if(selection.size() > 0){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


    return view;
}


class ViewHolder {
    TextView name, description;
    CheckBox select;
    Switch aSwitch;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the Checkbox?

Comment: In layout that will be represented in listview

Comment: use interface for callback on `checkbox` `checkedListener` and make dynamic visibility

Comment: what have you done to achieve this? Paste some code here.

Comment: possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149414/how-to-receive-a-event-on-android-checkbox-check-change

Comment: @Ali Turki So there will be more than one CheckBox, each for a row of ListView. You've to keep count of all Selected CheckBox. So you could make visible Button as count>0

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: When i `setVisibility` on button doesn't work but when i `getText` it's work fine,
do you have any idea @Bills

Comment: Your TextView will be in Activity and you want to change it from `LampControllerAdapter `. So, pass activity object in your adaptor in constructor and then set visibility after finding its id like `sC = (Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.selection_control);`

Comment: Big Thanks  @Bills :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
CheckBox chkBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.chkBox );
chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform your action here
        }

    }
});
```