# Increase score with each correct answer

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit stuck...new to android and Java (doing online course), and making a quiz app as a project. I have a question with 4 checkboxes, 2 of each are the correct answer. I want to increase the score by 5 with each correct answer (if 1/2 if ticked, you get 5 points, if both are ticked you get 10). I tried doing it with the OR operator, but I still get only 5 points even if both answers are ticked. Any way to work around this? Thanks
Here's a snipet of the relevant code:

```
 @Override
public void onClickNextButton(View v) {

    CheckBox checkBox1 = findViewById(R.id.terrance);
    CheckBox checkBox2 = findViewById(R.id.jimbo);
    CheckBox checkBox3 = findViewById(R.id.phillip);
    CheckBox checkBox4 = findViewById(R.id.ike);

    if (checkBox1.isChecked() || checkBox3.isChecked()) {
        MainActivity.score += 5;

    } else if (checkBox2.isChecked() || (checkBox4.isChecked())) {

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must pick an answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Answer_4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Because you use the OR operator, even if you select both correct answers, you still get 5 points only. One simple solutions is that check them in two separate if statements, e.g.,

    if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
    }

    if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see different solutions,  you could fix it with only adding few lines:

```
if (checkBox1.isChecked() || checkBox3.isChecked()) {
    if (checkBox1.isChecked())
        MainActivity.score += 5;
    if (checkBox3.isChecked())
        MainActivity.score += 5;
} else ...
```

Comment: yeah, sorry, i missed a line....it works now! such a simple solution...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suppose the chk1 and chk2 are correct answer, so you have to use different IF for each of them:

```
if (checkBox1.isChecked())
    MainActivity.score += 5;
if (checkBox3.isChecked())
    MainActivity.score += 5;
```

Another issue would be that you used **public void onClickNextButton(View v)** which is not proper for a Checkbox for your work, it would be better to use

> setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()...

take a look at [How to receive a event on android checkbox check change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149414/how-to-receive-a-event-on-android-checkbox-check-change)